# Searching for the best HTML5 to Java Framework

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex4, html5-canvas, flex3

WE have a finance and insurance product that build in Flex as front end and Java (EJB) as a backend using JBoss Application server, now we want to change the Front end from Flex to HTML5. the framework we are using in Flex is cairngorm that is I think best for flex to communicate with java using blazeds.
Now can anybody help me to choose the framework of HTML5, so that only Flex side will be replaced. As I told that application scope is very huge, thousands of flex files with custom components SWCs. please give me a proper framework so that I can raplace my Flex side with HTML5.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; please read the help section for more information about the site including types of questions that are considered appropriate here: http://stackoverflow.com/help The current question is asking for recommendations which is considered bad form.  That said: A lot of Flex Developer's love angularJS. A lot of people have had success with JQuery [and/or Backbone.js]. The Sencha tool chain is the closest thing to Flex in the JS space b/c it has paid support options and a huge UI library.  I'd start w/ those three options and see if one of those would work for you.

Comment: You are in for a world of hurt if you are looking to replace Flex with a JS framework.  I've tried the same, and it seems like building large apps with JS is like pounding a square peg into a round hole.  As far as your backend goes, it was done with BlazeDS.  If you are going for an SPA(Singe Page Application) you are going to have to consider what its going to take to jsonify those objects.  It shouldn't be difficult, but is something that must be on the roadmap.

Comment: We went with GWT+Sencha.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with Sencha/extjs, the latest version of the sencha can accept the amf protocol data on the client side, so you can just put your time and developing the UI rather than rewriting the services, also, it is powerful like flex and backed by a huge community. GWT may be good replacement, but it has its own problems, you end up writing a lot of code in Java. People say JQueryUI is good, I've never used it personally.

Adobe has started developing IDEs around html5, checkout adobe edge.